# Google DialogFlow: Query Firebase database's strategy/design

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have a project related to DialogFlow flow chart design where end-user want to look up their information in database (i'm assuming Firebase) based on Age and Gender.

I was actually a little confused because in order to query the information in Firebase, we need to know the "primary key" value which is obviously not Age or Gender.

So, it could work if we design a table with "customer id" as primary key and require customer to type or tell their ID.

For example, like the following workflow.

```
Customer: Hi
Bot: I'm BOT. How can i help you?
Customer: I want to know everything about me.
Bot: Please tel me your ID
Customer: ABC12345
Bot: Here's your information
```

Anyone has experiences with GoogleDialogFlow can help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have the customer id as a key in firebase.